# My flight from Venice to NYC was delayed 7 hours at the stopover in Kiev. Am I eligible for compensation?

Tags: delays, compensation

I booked a flight from Venice to NYC on Ukraine International Airlines.

9 days before I left, UIA notified me that they changed the time of the flight from Kiev to NYC to leave 5 hours later than originally scheduled.

(Also the flight from Venice to Kiev was delayed by an hour.)

Am I entitled to compensation?

Comment: Note that even if you are **entitled** to compensation, the airline may refuse to pay out and you might have to take them to court (or more likely credibly threaten to) to receive it. There are a number of legal firms who specialise in ensuring that airlines pay out in exchange for a hefty chunk of your compensation. Research such companies thoroughly, though, as they range from excellent to borderline-fraudulent.

Answer (score 9):

As your journey originated at an EU airport, it is covered by the [EU air passenger rights](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm).

Your booked flight was cancelled between 7 and 14 days in advance, and you were offered rerouting that would make you arrive at your *final destination* more than 4 hours late. This means that you're entitled to compensation. As the distance between origin and final destination is more than 3000 km, the compensation should be 600 euro.

(The delay on the first leg is is not relevant for this, because it did not contribute to you being late at your final destination).

The airline may try to wiggle out of paying compensation because the leg that was rescheduled was entirely outside the EU. However, this will not fly after the decision by the European Court of Justice in [Wegener v. Royal Air Maroc, ECLI:EU:C:2018:361](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A62017CJ0537) earlier this year. The court explicitly said that the air passenger rights keep applying after a layover outside EU/EEA, when the entire journey was booked together.